# How do I fix an error of run-time check failure #2 in C?

Tags: c

I keep gettin a run-time check failure #2 error.  It says the stack around the variable 'seats' and 'selection' is corrupted.  This occurs when I debug it and hit the part where I ask the user if they want to switch to either first class or economy class because the other one is full.  At that point the program stops working and the exception is thrown.  I have no idea how to fix this and I appreciate all the help I can get.

```
#include<stdio.h>

//Main program.
int main(void)
{
    //Declaring Variables
    int first = 1;
    int econ = 6;
    int input = 0;
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    //Declaring arrays.
    int seats[11] = { 1 };
    char selection[2];

    printf("Welcome to our automated reservation system!\n");

    // Loop for numver of seats
    while (counter < 10) {
        // prompt user for information
        printf("Please type 1 for First Class.\nPlease type 2 for Economy Class:");
        scanf_s("%d", &input);


        if (input == 1) {

            // Check if first class seats are available.
            if (!seats[first] && first <= 5) {
                printf("\nBoarding Pass:\nYour seat number is: %d in First Class\n\n", first);
                seats[first++] = 1;
                counter++;
            }

            // Else if statement to offer economy if first class is full. 
            else if (first > 5 && econ <= 10) {
                printf("\nFirst Class is all booked\n\nDo you want to switch to Economy Class?\nEnter Y to confirm:");
                scanf_s("%s", selection, strlen(selection));


                if (selection[0] == 'y' || selection[0] == 'Y') {
                    printf("\nBoarding Pass:\nYour seat number is: %d in Economy Class\n\n", econ);
                    seats[econ++] = 1;
                    counter++;
                }  

                else {
                    printf("\nNext flight leaves in 3 hours.\n\n");
                }
            }


            else {
                printf("\nNext flight leaves in 3 hours.\n\n");
            }

        }

        // Else if statement for economy class.
        else if (input == 2) {

            // Check if economy class seats are available.
            if (!seats[econ] && econ <= 10) {
                printf("\nBoarding Pass:\nYour seat number is: %d in Economy Class\n\n", econ);
                seats[econ++] = 1;
                counter++;
            }

            // if all economy seats are booked offer first class
            else if (econ > 10 && first <= 5) {
                printf("\nEconomy Class is all booked\n\nDo you want to switch to First Class?\nEnter Y to confirm:");
                scanf_s("%s", selection, strlen(selection));


                if (selection[0] == 'y' || selection[0] == 'Y') {
                    printf("\nBoarding Pass:\nYour seat number is: %d in First Class\n\n", first);
                    seats[first++] = 1;
                    counter++;
                }
                else {
                    printf("\nNext flight leaves in 3 hours.\n\n");
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("\nNext flight leaves in 3 hours.\n\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("\nInvalid selection. Please try again.\n\n");
        }

    }
    // Message for booked seats. 
    printf("All seats for this flight are now booked\n\nPlease contact customer service for additional services.\nThank you for using our automated reservation system.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It means that you are accessing the memory outside the arrays.

Comment: Please [edit] and provide an example of input that triggers the error. Read this: [mcve]. But anyway I'm pretty sure that the problem is due to your array indexes being out of range at some point (`seats` and/or `selection`).

Comment: scanf_s() helps you find bugs in your code by *intentionally* crashing your program.  The size of selection[] is 2, not strlen(selection).  It doesn't contain a valid string yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least one problem here:

```
scanf_s("%s", selection, strlen(selection));
```

You can use `strlen(selection)` only if `selection` contains a valid string, and this is not the case until `scanf_s("%s", selection, strlen(selection))` has been used to input the string. It's a kind of chicken and egg problem.

So intead of

```
scanf_s("%s", selection, strlen(selection));
```

use

```
scanf_s("%s", selection, sizeof(selection) - 1);
```

or just drop this `scanf_s` nonsense and use this:

```
scanf("%1s", selection);
```